# Draw horizontal line for average on y axis in Echarts

Tags: vue.js, charts, vuejs2, chart.js, echarts

I would like to draw a horizontal line showing average using EChart.JS.

Do I need to calculate average programmatically and use MaskLine for this or does echarts provides a builtin way to do it?

Additionally my x-axis has dates information, how do I specify start and end point?

Comment: Have you tried `mapValueCalculation`? The default value is `sum` but you can change it to `average`. https://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/doc-en.html

Comment: I am using apache echarts https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts and it does not have any property like mapValueCalculation.

Comment: I found `mapValueCalculation` property in the repo:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/search?q=mapValueCalculation
Also look for that property name in their wiki:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/wiki/ECharts-2-FAQ
I think the language is Chinese which I cannot understand. I hope that helps.